# Rails Hpricot gem: Unable to get the link content from xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hpricot

I am using Hpricot gem to parse xml. I am able to get title and pubdate but it did not work for link. Here is the code snippet

```
items = doc.search("//item").first(6)
items.each do |item|
  feed = {}
  feed[:title] = item.search("//title").text
  feed[:link] = item.search("//link").text
  feed[:published_date] = item.search("//pubdate").text
  feeds << feed
end
```

The resultant hpricot elements are as follows:

```
#<Hpricot::Elements[{elem <item> "\n\t\t" {elem <title> "openagent.com.au" </title>} "\n\t\t" {emptyelem <link>} "http://blog.iproperty.com.au/2016/03/22/openagent-com-au/" {bogusetag </link>} "\n\t\t" {elem <comments> "http://blog.iproperty.com.au/2016/03/22/openagent-com-au/#comments" </comments>} "\n\t\t" {elem <pubdate> "Mon, 21 Mar 2016 22:43:28 +0000" </pubDate>} "\n\t\t"
```

I have pasted the initial part as it is the only part which is important. Can anyone tell what is the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
items = doc.search("//item").first(6)
items.each do |item|
  feed = {}
  feed[:title] = item.search("//title").text
  feed[:link] = item.search("//link").innerHTML
  feed[:published_date] = item.search("//pubdate").text
  feeds << feed
end
```

for getting link we can use innerHTML

Comment: It did not work. When i do 
item.search("//link") it gives me this
#<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <link>}]>

And innerHTML for it will return empty string.

Comment: Hpricot gem has tags set please use proper tag please refer this link [link](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot/blob/master/lib/hpricot/tags.rb)